# Can't animating the height of the closest parent of a toggle button?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to animate the height of the closest parent of a toggle button:

CSS

```
    .review-item {
        background: #E8E8E2;
        height: 26px;
        margin-top: 15px;
        overflow: hidden;
        padding: 15px;
```

(etc.)

JS:

```
    $(".submit-review-toggle").toggle(function(){
        $(this).closest('.review-item').animate({height:168},200);
    },function(){
        $(this).closest('.review-item').animate({height:26},200);
    });
```

HTML:

```
  <div id="review-item-1" class="review-item">
    <a href="#" class="submit-review-toggle review-item-toggle">+</a>

    <h3>Service</h3>

    <div class="review-overview">
      <textarea name="message" placeholder="Overview" class="submit-review-overview">
</textarea>
    </div>

    <div class="review-photo">
      <img src="images/no-photo.png" />

      <div class="review-photo-upload">
        <input type="file" class="file-upload" /><a href="#" class=
        "facebook-import">Import pictures from Facebook</a>
      </div><input type="text" placeholder="Caption" class="caption" />
    </div>
  </div>
```

For some reason, when i click the link nothing happen.
Any suggestions to fix this?

Comment: Works fine for me -> http://jsfiddle.net/manseuk/N4hMw/ perhaps its CSS related - can you add the remainder ? or update the jsfiddle - or make sure you have your JS enclosed within `$(document).ready(function() { });` to ensure the DOM is loaded before the listener is added

Comment: what's your problem....here is no error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is working for me, check: http://jsfiddle.net/5wh6v/